# Passing Parameters to pthread_create

Tags: c

I have a structure named graph.

graph *G;

Now I create memory of size of structure using malloc and the start pointer is stored in pointer G.

G = (graph*)malloc(sizeof(graph));

My question is how do I pass this as a argument to pthread_create?

pthread_create(&th,NULL,function_call, ? );

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `C` rather than `C++`?

Comment: Also, this is more of an implementation question than a design question, so should be asked on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Ya but then since I have posted it here already.. Why not answer it?

Comment: just like in a [previous question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/276503/error-during-including-c-header-file#comment567671_276503), I wonder, are you by chance [blocked at Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)

Comment: This question does not appear to be about software development within the scope defined in the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601

Comment: @NandiniSinghal: That's a rather self-centered response. As for why: 1) because the question can be transferred to SO, 2) because you can ask at SO (unless you're blocked, as gnat wonders, in which case Programmers.SE isn't simply a way to circumvent the block), 3) Q&A isn't just for you–it's for everyone who has the same question. If you ask on an off-topic site, those people are less likely to find the question. Also, the Q becomes noise, making it harder for others to search this site for on-topic questions. I know you want answers, but it's not just about you: it's about the community.

Comment: ... Also, you could have easily answered the question yourself by reading the appropriate documentation (basically, anything on pthreads). Search for info on "man pages" (unless you're already familiar, in which case, read them).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the prototype of pthread_create is

```
 int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

As the *arg* parameter is a void* you can simply write

```
pthread_create(&th,NULL,function_call, G);
```

However, it the function_call(), you will need to cast you *arg* parameter to the real type.
either:

```
function_call(void *arg)
{
    graph *tmp_G;

    tmp_G = arg;
    //  then I use tmp_G as G
}
```

or

```
((graph *)arg)->the_field_of_G;
```

Then you will be able to use you parameter as you need.

If you want to give more then one parameter to you function, you simply have to create a new structure that will contain all your parameters, then cast it as above to use them in your function_call().

here is an example :

```
typedef struct s_my_function_call_arg
{
    graph *G;
    int   arg2;
    char  *arg3;
}              t_my_function_call_arg;
```

Comment: ssca2.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:           
ssca2.cpp:169:63: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL,genScalData,G);
                                                               ^
In file included from ssca2.cpp:79:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
            ^

Comment: The answer is writtend in your compilation error messages :  invalid conversion from ‘void ()(void)’ to ‘void* ()(void). The return value of genScalData is suppose to be void *.